# AWS Cognito Identity Service Provider appears to store access token in local storage. Is this safe?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, access-token

We are developing an application that uses a React front end website hosted on AWS using Amplify. This communicates with a .NET Core 3.1 Web API running on EC2 / Elastic Beanstalk. Cognito is used for user authentication with the Web API configured to use JWT tokens.

It works OK, but we have noticed that the Cognito provider stores the JWT access token in the browser local storage. This is what we see using F12 in Chrome and inspecting local storage.

[image]

From what we have read, storing access tokens in local storage is not advised as it makes the application susceptible to XSS attacks. Strange then, that the Cognito identity provider chooses to store sensitive information here.

If this approach is not considered safe, can the provider be configured to store this information elsewhere, such as cookies?

Alternatively, as we control both front and back ends, is there an alternative method that can be used to secure the API that does not involve tokens? Obviously the API needs to know which user is logged on to the web application in order to perform authorization checks. [Note authorization in the application is record level and defined in database tables, so it goes beyond simple user profile attributes.]

Many thanks in advance for your advice.

Doug

Answer (score 7):

Security is a spectrum not a feature so it really depends on your appetite for risk vs effort. Amplify is not a particularly nice codebase, it has 500+ issues and if you look at the code you might be fairly shocked at the quality of it.

If you are using Hosted-UI then you can write code to manage the tokens yourself rather than using amplify, although you will need to learn a bit about OAuth grants and OIDC.

Be aware that the Hosted UI lacks a huge amount of features, so if you are going to use it make sure you are happy with it. Off the top of my head

- no silent refresh capability in the hosted UI, so no safe way to store the refresh token.
- no support for custom auth flow in the hosted UI
- no passwordless support in the hosted UI
- no ability to pre-populate a field in the hosted UI (e.g. username)
- no ability to customise the plethora of obscure error messages in the custom UI
- fixed now, but for years the email addresses were case sensitive!

An alternative is also to just use the AWS SDK to get tokens directly using cognito-idp but this also has a bunch of issues:

- no code/PKCE/nonce capability so insecure in a mobile authsession
- no ability to set oauth scopes, so can't use them
- consequently not possible to use for OIDC
- the SRP implementation is bananas and so far off spec
- if you make device registration mandatory, it will deliver a working access tokens before the device is registered! (allows invisible devices for malicious logins)

We were using auth0 which was leagues ahead but we had to move to Cognito because of SMS OTP cost (min $25k per year at auth0).

I have been using AWS for over a decade now, Cognito is *by far* the worst service I have used, and I have used a lot! If you can avoid it, do so.

To answer the original question, yeah it's insecure. The best you can probably do is keep them in memory. If you wanted to you could probably put the hosted UI behind a cloudfront and use an lambda@edge to transform the token into a cookie instead. This has now opened you up to CSRF attacks though.

Comment: Many thanks for your extensive answer. Our level of expertise is obviously not as high as yours! In the end, we decided to use a custom storage object for the tokens. This still uses local storage, but encrypts the data stored there.

Answer (score 1):

answering the original question: no, it is not safe at all.
Storing refreshtoken in any local storage accessable to any local app/script is not secure. So, the best way would be to store the refreshoten (and also the access token) in an httponly cookie or even better to store a one-time session token in httponly secure cookie could be used to get new access and refresh cookies - similarly as it is made by cognito hosted ui with XSRF-TOKEN.
See below how I would solve (and plan to solve) this issue:

Some background:
Due to GDPR regulations I think I can not use the cognito hosted ui - I have to make sure users read and accept the general terms and conditions (giving clear and auditable consent) and can review and accept cookie policies as well before they type in any user data for sign up. Nevertheless the built in hosted ui design is quite outdated and unflexible. I have an SPA website where I want to manage users, secure endpoints, etc.

So I have the following idea which is still not super secure but I think it is more secure one if you want to use js and ampify sdk and which also might answer your question:
I'll use amplify javascript sdk to let users sign up, change psw and log in (get tokenid, access token and refresh token), will make my own "hosted ui". I'll store the access token in memory only (not in local cookies and not in localstorage for sure). Access token will be used in header (bearer) to access apiGW endpoints. Access tokens will have very short expire dates.  (I'd also use httponly secure cookies sent back by the apigw, as well as in the body.., then compare at BE side..)

And here comes the trick: I'd cut the refresh token into two. (Don't forget it is just a string.) I'd store the first part of the string in a local cookie (javascript can read it, if browser is closed and opened again it will be still there) and will send the other half of the refresh token to an apiGW endpoint (accessable without authentication) which will store it in a dynamoDB table (with TTL) and will send back an httponly secure cookie to the browser with a randomly generated "storagetoken" in it (which will be a key in dynamodb). There will be another unauthenticated apigw endpoint which will be called by the client whenever the client needs the full refresh token. Calling this endpoint the browser will send in the httponly secure cookie as well (same domain), so the backend will get it. As it is issued by the BE and available only in the given browser it can not be stolen so the backend  will send back the stored half refreshtoken. The other half part of refreshtoken is stored in a simple cookie in the browser.

If the browser is closed and opened again client checks if there is any valid accesstoken and if not it checks if there is a half refeshtoken stored as cookie. Then ask the other part of refreshtoken assuming there is a httponlycookie also stored and it will get back the other part of the refreshtoken from the BE. In case of success the client tries to use the full refreshtoken to renew/get access token from cognito, in case of failure it will pop up the login screen.
Whenever refreshtoken is not in use it is deleted from the memory.

I know this is still not supersecure but might be a better solution than storing refresh token in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, as we control both front and back ends, is there an alternative method that can be used to secure the API that does not involve tokens?

I don't know anything of Amplify but in AWS Cognito what you describe is the `Implicit grant` OAuth flow. In AWS Cognito it is possible to use `Authorization code grant` where you instead of the token get a code which you in the backend can exchange for a user pool token.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-app-integration.html